# DidselectRowAtIndexPath not returning indexPath.row as expected/desired

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

- I have a view with 11 rows which contains textfields, textViews
- Total height of all the elements > **ScreenHeight**
- I have a textfield as the second last element.
- Empty row as the last element

To present this View, I used TableView

- I use different identifier for different types of elements.
- In `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, I return cell based on `indexaPath.row`
- The view is displayed as expected.
- I scroll and still rows are displayed as expected

Since Textfield is at the end and keyboard is presented, so

- When textField is clicked
- I move the `tableView.frame` up by `keyboard.height`
- It moves up correctly.
- I see `cellForIndexPath` called for last element (indexPath.row = 10)

**Now the problem starts**

- textField.cell.row = 9 (10th Element)
- To dismiss keyboard, I press on the cell below the "`textFieldCell`" (last element) **which is expected to be a row with indexPath.row = 10**
- In textField.didEndEditing, I reset `tableView.frame = originalFrame`
- I `scrollToBottomAnimated`
- Now I see, iOS calling `cellForIndexPath` = 7,6,5,4
- But **`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`** gives me the rowNumber = 7 `which is not what I clicked`.
- I clicked row 11th or `indexPath.row` = 10

But due to resizing of tableView and scolling, things went wrong.

What am I doing wrong.

What do I need to do to get indexPath.row = 10 and not 7 when I click the last cell?

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"moveView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];

    self.frame=CGRectMake(0,66,ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight - keyboardFrame.size.height-66);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self scrollToBottomRowAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"moveView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];
    self.frame=CGRectMake(0,66,ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight - 66);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self scrollToBottomRowAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)scrollToBottomRowAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    long lastRowNumber = [self numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
    [self scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:animated];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(indexPath.row);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

Comment: If you have a problem with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you may want to show the source code for it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect (not sure though) the problem is you are mixing two types of animations really and in the approach to shrinking the table view to compensate for keyboard.

Do not use tableview frame change via committed animations. Instead I recommend using a trivial vertical content offset in the table view. UITableView is really a UIScrollView subclass, so it has all the methods for scrollview and it supports vertical content offset for its content.

In textfieldDidBeginEditing:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, kKeyboardHeight) animated:YES];
```

and in textfieldDidEndEditing just get rid of the offset via

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Comment: To further hypothesise on the reason why you see 7 instead of 10, i think behind the scenes CoreAnimation is used and what is animated is the presentationLayer and your standard layer is actually not moving so the area where you tap still contains cell no.7.

Comment: your recommendation does work........I will try understand this better now....thanks a LOT!!!!